# Resizing the boxplot

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, boxplot

I am displaying the following boxplot and would like to give it style features like: resize it to 400x800px , display it in the middle of the html file... Now I cant see the x axis labels for example because of the size... Any help?

Please check the complete code on this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CPDVExRlryA5j25zpyiy?p=preview).

The script is starting like this:

```
var labels = true; // show the text labels beside individual boxplots?

var margin = {top: 25, right: 25, bottom: 25, left: 25};
var  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var min = 0,
    max = 10;

// parse in the data    
d3.csv("boxplot_year.csv", function(error, csv) {

    var data = [];
    data[0] = [];
    data[1] = [];
    data[2] = [];
    data[3] = [];
    data[4] = [];
    data[5] = [];

    data[0][0] = "Y2010";
    data[1][0] = "Y2011";
    data[2][0] = "Y2012";
    data[3][0] = "Y2013";
    data[4][0] = "Y2014";
    data[5][0] = "Y2015";

    data[0][1] = [];
    data[1][1] = [];
    data[2][1] = [];
    data[3][1] = [];
    data[4][1] = [];
    data[5][1] = [];



    csv.forEach(function(x) {
        var v1 = Math.floor(x.Y2010),
            v2 = Math.floor(x.Y2011),
            v3 = Math.floor(x.Y2012),
            v4 = Math.floor(x.Y2013),
            v5 = Math.floor(x.Y2014),
            v6 = Math.floor(x.Y2015);

        var rowMax = Math.max(Math.max(v1,v2), Math.max(Math.max(v3,v4), Math.max(v5,v6)));
        var rowMin = Math.min(Math.min(v1,v2), Math.min(Math.min(v3,v4), Math.min(v5,v6)));

        data[0][1].push(v1);
        data[1][1].push(v2);
        data[2][1].push(v3);
        data[3][1].push(v4);
        data[4][1].push(v5);
        data[5][1].push(v6);

        if (rowMax > max) max = rowMax;
        if (rowMin < min) min = rowMin; 
    });

    var boxplot = d3.box()
        .whiskers(iqr(1.5))
        .height(height) 
        .domain([min, max])
        .showLabels(labels);

    var svg = d3.select("#boxplot").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("class", "box")    
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // the x-axis
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()     
        .domain( data.map(function(d) { console.log(d); return d[0]; } ) )      
        .rangeRoundBands([0 , width], 0.7, 0.3);        

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    // the y-axis
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([min, max])
        .range([height + margin.top, 0 + margin.top]);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    // draw the boxplots    
    svg.selectAll(".box")      
        .data(data)
       .enter().append("g")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +  x(d[0])  + "," + margin.top + ")"; } )
        .call(boxplot.width(x.rangeBand()));

    // draw y axis
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
        .append("text") // and text1
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "10px") 
            .text("Grade");     

    // draw x axis  
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height  + margin.top + 10) + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
        .append("text") // text label for the x axis
            .attr("x", (width / 2) )
            .attr("y",  10 )
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "10px") 
            .text("Year"); 
});

// Returns a function to compute the interquartile range.
function iqr(k) {
    return function(d, i) {
        var q1 = d.quartiles[0],
            q3 = d.quartiles[2],
            iqr = (q3 - q1) * k,
            i = -1,
            j = d.length;
        while (d[++i] < q1 - iqr);
        while (d[--j] > q3 + iqr);
        return [i, j];
    };
}
```

Comment: Just adjust the bottom axis margin, like [this here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MCDiRluruarzmUhVA1j7?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks @Mark and to make both axis unite in the 0? And can you think of a way to avoid writing "Y2010"? I want to have just 2010, but the javascript will not accept it; as Y2010 is a string and 2010 a number (Setting 2010 as a string has not worked for me neither...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the bottom margin to 100. This is sufficient to show the bottom y-axis.

```
var margin = {top: 25, right: 25, bottom: 100, left: 25};
```

Based on your comment, to make both axis unite at 0 add a transform to your y-axis

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate (0,10)") 
        .call(yAxis)
```

To get rid of the Y from Y2010 add a slice to your labels like below. However be aware that it is changing your data so in your console log you will see years as 2010, 2011 etc.

```
// the x-axis
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()     
    .domain( data.map(function(d) { d[0] = d[0].slice(1); console.log(d); return d[0]; } ) )        
    .rangeRoundBands([0 , width], 0.7, 0.3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful indeed. One last question, to get the label of the y axis in the left of the axis and in the middle, what should I do? @Coola

Comment: By label I assume you mean "Grade" right? If that is the case you can change the x and y values to move it around by changing the             `.attr("y", 6)  .attr("dy", ".71em")`

Comment: Yes, that is right, is moving "Grade". I tried what you told me but it is not working... @Coola

Comment: Since the label is rotated you have to use `.attr("x", height/2);` to move it up and down the plot. Then change the `.attr("y", -25)` to push the label outside the ticks on the left and increase the margin on the left to 40 so that there is enough space to view the label. `var margin = {top: 25, right: 25, bottom: 100, left: 40};`. If this is not what you want, please create another question with a more detailed description of what you would like and an updated plunker.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the width and height attributes on your svg and make it expand to full size of its outer container using the `viewBox` attribute, replace the `var svg` part as follows, I hard coded the `viewBox`, change it as you see fit:

```
var svg = d3.select("#boxplot").append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox","0 0 800 800")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio","none")
        .style("display","block")
        .style("width","100%")
        .style("height","100%")
        .attr("class", "box")    
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Since you now make your svg expand as much as possible, only modify the outer div as you see fit, either on "resize", periodically etc. To better understand what `viewBox` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox